# Python: convert 2 ints to 32 float

Tags: python

How can I combine 2 ints to a single 32bit IEEE floating point ? (each of the 2 ints represent 16 bit)
And in the opposite direction: How can I transform a python float into 2 16 bit ints?

(I need this because of modbus protocol - where 2x16 bit registers are treated as single 32 floating point number)

Comment: Be wary of treating Python floats as 32-bit IEEE - they are actually 64-bit. So if you unpack your 32 bits to a float it will really be 64-bit, and I'm not sure of the rounding implications of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code takes the 16 bits integers i1 and i2 and convert them to the floating point number 3.14, and vice versa.

```
from struct import *
# Two integers to a floating point
i1 = 0xC3F5
i2 = 0x4840
f = unpack('f',pack('>HH',i1,i2))[0]

# Floating point to two integers
i1, i2 = unpack('>HH',pack('f',3.14))
```

Comment: This doesn't always work. For example on my machine if I try `i1 = i2 = 32895`, create `f` and then unpack again I get `i2` back out as 49279. In this case it's because the floating point generated was `nan`, which has some special characteristics.

Comment: If that's an issue for the OP, he can check if f is nan:
    
    if math.isnan(f):
        i1 = i2 = 32895
    else:
        i1, i2 = unpack('>HH',pack('f',f))

Or he can try python-bitstring (http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/). Does is it handle this case correctly?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to check for nan (there are many combinations that fail in the same way - I only gave one example). The bitstring module isn't going to help with the fundamental problem of going via the Python float type (it uses struct internally in any case). The solution is to keep the data as bytes (for which bitstring might be helpful), but the details depend on the exact nature of the OP's problem.

Comment: In `i1, i2 = unpack('>HH',pack('f',3.14))` I had to place a '>' before the f in struct.pack, so it worked as `i1, i2 = unpack('>HH',pack('>f',123.45))` Maybe it will help if some of you were looking for some solution.

Answer (score 0):

The standard `struct` module can be used to do this easily. Just be careful of your platform endianess but, other than that, it should be a pretty straight-forward application of `pack()` and `unpack()`.

Comment: something like unpack('>f', pack('hh, int1, int2)) ??

Comment: Yep. If it doesn't "just work", you're probably running into an endianess issue. The easiest way I've found to figure out what's going wrong is to use a small test script with hexidecimal constants that you can use while you fiddle with the pack/unpack options till you get the results you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think this method will work reliably - see my comment on Alejandro's answer.

Comment: @Scott Bit manipulation of floating-point values is inherently tricky the `struct` module makes such manipulation possible but doesn't free you from the responsibility using it appropriately.