# convert 2 ints to 32 float which works for all cases

Tags: python, floating-point, int

Looking at question [Python: convert 2 ints to 32 float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063078/python-convert-2-ints-to-32-float) it is shown that two intgers can be converted to a floating point number. The solution given was:

```
from struct import pack, unpack
f = unpack('>f',pack('>HH',i1,i2))[0]
```

In the comments it was pointed out that this will not work for all cases. I need to integrate a way to convert two integers to floating point for a production piece of code, so all cases will have to be accounted for. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: The caveats on that answer apply only to the conversion in the other direction (float to 2 ints), if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, I will not be going the other direction, so if this is the case the above code will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The caveats in the comments on that answer *only* apply for the reverse operation.

For *all* unsigned 16-bit integers `i1` and `i2`, packing to bytes then unpacking as float will work without problems.

If you have the time, you can verify this yourself for all 4294+ million combinations with:

```
from struct import pack, unpack
for i1, i2 in product(xrange(2**16), repeat=2):
    try:
        f = unpack('>f', pack('>HH', i1, i2))
    except Exception:
        print 'Fails for {}, {}'.format(i1, i2)
```

Or, just take my word for it.